# Combinatorial Identity for sum of number over powers 0 to n-1

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to come up with a counting argument for: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}q^{k-1} = \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$.  I am trying to base it off of counting the left side as the sum of the (k-1) length words from an alphabet of size q for $k=1$ to $k=n-1$, but I can't seem to come up with a fitting argument to count the right side of the equation.

Comment: You mean the sum to $n$, right?

Comment: O yes, it seems to have been edited by someone. Should be from k=1 to n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Fix a letter $a$ of your alphabet; there are $q^n-1$ words of length $n$ that contain at least one letter different from $a$.

Now count the same set of words according to the position of the last non-$a$ letter. If this is position $k$, $k$ can have any value from $1$ through $n$; how many words of length $n$ have the last non-$a$ letter in position $k$?

Answer (score -1):

The proof is not a combinatorial argument.   It's an algebraic argument.

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
(q-1)\sum_{k=1}^n q^{n-1} & = (q-1)(q^{n-1}+q^{n-2}+\ldots + q^1+q^0)
\\[1ex] & = (q^n+\cancel{q^{n-1}+\ldots + q^2 + q^1}) -( \cancel{q^{n-1}+ \ldots+q^2+q^1}+q^0)
\\[2ex] & = q^n -1
\end{align}$$

Therefore $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n q^{n-1} = \dfrac{q^n-1}{q-1}$

That is all.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  This is an interesting solution, however I am working through an exercise that asks for a combinatorial argument.