# Proofs using double count

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to argue the following by counting in two ways. Any help is appreciated.

a)  ${2n\choose n}=2{2n-1\choose n-1}$

b)  $\Sigma_k {k\choose l}{n\choose k}={n\choose l}2^{n-l}$

c)  $\Sigma_{k=1}^n q^{k-1}=\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$

d)  $\Sigma_{i=1}^n i(n-i)=\Sigma_{i=1}^n {i\choose 2}$

Answer (score 1):

Here's one for (a):

Let's choose a subset of $n$ elements from the set $[2n] = \{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$: on the one hand, this quantity is equal to $\binom{2n}{n}$.  On the other hand, every subset of $n$ elements from $[2n]$ either has the element $2n$ or it doesn't; if it does, we can remove it leaving a subset of $n - 1$ elements from the set $[2n-1]$.  If it doesn't have the element $[2n]$, then it is a subset of $n$ elements from the set $[2n]$.  We thus have that this quantity is equal to $\binom{2n-1}{n} + \binom{2n - 1}{n - 1} = 2\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Marcus M** has already given a suggestion for (a).

For (b) imagine that you have a pool of $n$ players and are to choose a team of $\ell$ players and any number of reserves from $0$ through $n-\ell$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1439175/12042) is a hint for (c).

For (d) imagine that you’re to choose a set of three different numbers from the set $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.

- Suppose that the middle number of the three is $i$; how many ways are there to choose a smaller number and a larger number?
- Now suppose that the largest number of the three is $i$; how many ways are there to choose two smaller numbers?